# How to group data and store into array with specific key

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures

I have getting some data which is somewhat look like this.

```
var myData = [{Name : "Alex",Roll : 1,Class :   1,Marks :[{Maths: 100,Science : 200}],Weight: 50},        
            {Name : "Brat",Roll : 2,Class : 2,Marks :[{English: 100,History : 200 }],Weight: 40},
            {Name : "Brat",Roll : 2,Class : 2,Marks :[{English: 100,History : 200 }],Weight: 30},
            {Name : "Alex",Roll : 1,Class :1,   Marks :[{Maths: 100,Science : 200, }],Weight: 60},
            {Name : "Cean",Roll : 3,Class :1,   Marks :[{Physic: 100,Economics : 200, }],Weight: 40}]
```

What I have tried is this code.

```
function groupBy(xs, f) {
  return xs.reduce((r, v, i, a, k = f(v)) => ((r[k] || (r[k] = [])).push(v), r), {});
}
```

This is grouping the data but I want to store into array. Two keys should be outside and after that remaining stuff should be inside an array under collection.

```
newData = [{Name : "Alex",
            Roll: 1, 
            collection :[{Name : "Alex",Roll : 1,Class :    1,Marks :[{Maths: 100,Science : 200}],Weight: 50},
                         {Name : "Alex",Roll : 1,Class :1,  Marks :[{Maths: 100,Science : 200, }],Weight: 60}]
            },
            {Name : "Brat",
            Roll: 2, 
            collection :[{Name : "Brat",Roll : 2,Class : 2,Marks :[{English: 100,History : 200 }],Weight: 40},
                         {"Brat",Roll : 2,Class : 2,Marks :[{English: 100,History : 200 }],Weight: 30}]
            },
            {Name : "Cean",
            Roll: 3, 
            collection :[{Name : "Cean",Roll : 3,Class :1,  Marks :[{Physic: 100,Economics : 200, }],Weight: 40}],
            }
            ]
```

Can anybody help me to modify my code and help meto reach the solution.

[image: Objext]

Comment: @Rajesh No this is not duplicate. I have to store my data into array, There data is adding as object.

Comment: Group the values and then use `Object.values` to get array of values or loop over keys to get value array: `Object.keys(obj).map((key) => obj[key])` should do it

Comment: @Rajesh But in this case grouping is not happening right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Roll` as key, if it's present add the `current element` to collection property of that particular `Roll` else initialize with default structure

```js
const myData = [{Name : "Alex",Roll : 1,Class : 1,Marks :[{Maths: 100,Science : 200}],Weight: 50},{Name : "Brat",Roll : 2,Class : 2,Marks :[{English: 100,History : 200 }],Weight: 40},{Name : "Brat",Roll : 2,Class : 2,Marks :[{English: 100,History : 200 }],Weight: 30},{Name : "Alex",Roll : 1,Class :1,   Marks :[{Maths: 100,Science : 200, }],Weight: 60},{Name : "Cean",Roll : 3,Class :1,   Marks :[{Physic: 100,Economics : 200, }],Weight: 40}]            
 
let grouped = myData.reduce( (op,inp) => {
  let { Roll } = inp
  if( op[Roll] ) {
    op[Roll].collection.push(inp)
  } else{
    op[Roll] = {Name: inp.Name, Roll, collection:[{...inp}]}
  }
  return op
},{})

console.log(Object.values(grouped))
```

Comment: Yes, I can make Roll as a key and check the condition. Thanks Great

Comment: But this is not adding into array. This is behaving like object inside object. I have attach the image in question. @CodeManiac

Comment: @David this is giving the expected result, as you mentioned in question, did you tried running the snippet of answer ? most probably you're not using `Object.values(grouped)` to get values in the form of array

Comment: Yes I missed that part. Thanks :)